# Netezza - Schedule Stored Procedure

Tags: shell, netezza

How to schedule a stored procedure in Netezza to run in specific intervals? Looking for replacement of DBMS_JOB or DBMS_SCHEDULER in Oracle . Or is it possible to invoke Netezza stored procedure through shell script?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

in our project we are calling the stored proc using nzsql(in shell script) and shell script is scheduled using autosys. if you are using any ETL tools like informatica u can use stored procedure transformation to execute netezza procedures.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct equivalent to DBMS_SCHEDULER or DBMS_JOBS in Netazza. Stored procedures, just like any SQL, can be called through a shell script using the nzsql CLI utility. Those shell scripts can then be scheduled to run via cron, or any another myriad of scheduling mechanisms.